# Why does the event not fire until after the parallel threads finish?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, parallel-processing

I am getting a list of items and putting them in a ListView. This list can be extensive so I use a Parallel.ForEach() to deal with the construction of the ListObjects.

After each item is instantiated I fire an event on the UI thread to add the item to the ListView. My logging is indicating to me that the events are waiting until the parallel tasks are completed before proceeding with the AddItem event. This doesn't help me. I need the display to update as quickly as possible but if it's waiting on an event anyway why run parallel?

Should I not use events for this? Would this be better served by creating a delegate to hold the UI callback method and use that instead?

Comment: It's been a while since I've written one but I recall a method to create a list control that has a count of items but doesn't actually contain anything. Instead of holding everything in the control it asks its controller to fill in the data for visible items on demand. It's really efficient.

Comment: OK, the problem was that Parallel.ForEach does not execute on a separate thread than the one it was started on. So it was using the UI thread (along with two others) and any scheduling was done for after the Parallel.ForEach loop finished.

Once I put the Parallel.ForEach inside a Task.Factory.StartNew it put the ForEach on a different thread and the work got done exactly the way I thought it should.

Comment: Code requested above:
`
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(FileSystemInfoList, ListItemOptions, (WorkItem) =>
                    {
                        //Task Body
                        ItemCreator_DoWork_2(WorkItem);
                    });
            });
`


(OK, how do you do the code mark-up?)

Comment: public void ItemCreator_DoWork_2(ListViewItem )
{
...create specialized ListViewItem...

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                OnAddItemProgress(new AddItemProgressEventArgs(CurrentPercentage, NewList));
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            uiScheduler);
}

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the purpose of the `Parallel.ForEach()` is to improve the completion time for populating the ListView.  But you still have to wait for the ListView to completely load before you can display it.

If you want something that you can view while it is populating, you might try an [**`ObservableCollection`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).  But you should be cautious; the resulting UI activity might drag down the performance of your application.

Comment: Hmm, when I was using the BackgroundWorker from 3.5 I could raise the event just fine. The BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event would synch back to the UI thread for me (rather than use the FromCurrentSynchronizationContext) but that was the only difference. And it still doesn't answer my initial question of why the event waits for the threads to finish before firing.

I will give the class you mention a good hard look but this is a WinForms app and I'm not sure how easy implementing a WPF object would be. It at least gives me a couple of ideas.

Comment: Although the example given in the MSDN page is a WPF application, ObservableCollection is not (strictly speaking) a WPF class.  It can be used anywhere.

Comment: I don't know the exact, technical reason why it waits, but when you think about it, it does make sense. What makes `Parallel.For` feasible is the implicit assumption of thread safety within your larger task; it assumes that there are no side effects or outside forces that might interfere with the completion of the overall task. In other words, you can't just reach into the loop while it is running.

Comment: As mentioned above, the Parallel.ForEach does not execute on a different thread. It includes the thread it's on in it's scheduling.

Start a task on a new thread and then the Parallel.ForEach will let go of the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but it is what I think may be an improved way to get the results you want.

I found the thing I was looking for. It's a Virtual ListView, aka a ListView in VirtualMode.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx